# Add js library to Vue prototype?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an app which uses vue and laravel with laravel mix, I installed a js library called ProgressBar.js via npm install, however now I don't know how to use that library in my .vue files, how can I use the library inside my single file components, maybe adding it to the vue prototype, but how can I require it now?

https://progressbarjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#install

Answer (score 1):

If you started your Vue app with `vue create` command, you can simply import it in your App.vue. Example:

```
<script>
import ProgressBar from 'progressbar.js'

export default {
  mounted() {
    const line = new ProgressBar.Line('#container')
  }
}
</scirpt>
```

Comment: I actually do something like this: const app = new Vue({

el: '#vueapp',
store,

Comment: Is it just in plain html file your new Vue instance?

Comment: If it's simply an HTML file, then you have add a `<script>` tag with `src` to `node_modules/progressbar.js/dist/progressbar.js` and then use it directly from window in your Vue instance. window.Progressbar